# how to access a database files via the command line mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line-interface

I just installed mysql for the first time and created a databse with create database foo;
I think I have found where mysql stores the databases (/var/lib/mysql). When I try to cd to the foo directory I get permission denied. When I try with sudo nothing happens.

output of ls -l

```
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql    16384 Feb 21 17:44 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql       52 Feb 21 17:44 aria_log_control
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql     4096 Mar  1 22:08 foo
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 18874368 Feb 21 17:44 ibdata1
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  5242880 Mar  1 16:05 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  5242880 Feb 21 17:34 ib_logfile1
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb 21 17:34 mysql
srwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql        0 Mar  1 16:05 mysql.sock
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb 21 17:34 performance_schema
```

I know your meant to view the databases and stuff through that application on the command line but I am interested as to why I can't view the foo directory when i am root.

Answer (score 2):

You can't view the foo directory because of the permissions:

```
owner - mysql - read, write, execute
group - mysql - no access
other - no access
```

Comment: I thought root could access everything. If not could I chown the directory and then access it?

Comment: @user3247608 "I thought root could access everything" I also thought so. But the permissions seem to be the most probable explanation. Please, try to chmod o+rx. Because if you chown to root, mysql wouldn't be able to read the databases.

Answer (score 0):

First connect to mysql from command prompt using

```
[root@host]# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:******
```

Now select the database using

```
mysql> USE DB_Name
```

You can use belo command to  have the list of databases

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
```

To get the directory details you can use

```
mysql -uUSER -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = "dir_name"
```